# Getting expected a type and <UIKit/UIKit.h>" file not found in xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

While building the .ipa file in x-code I am getting the error below as shown in below image

[image]

Answer (score 3):

change

```
#import "<UIKit/UIKit.h>"
```

to

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Comment: thank you solved my error but expected type still showing